# Ptolemy's theorem. How to prove?

Tags: geometry, inequality

For distinct points $A, B, C, D$ on a plane, we have $(AB).(CD) + (AD).(BC) \geq (AC).(BD)$. Equality happens if and only if $A,B,C,D$ are collinear or concyclic with $A,C$ separating $B,D$.

Comment: Please check here [Link](https://planetmath.org/ProofOfPtolemysInequality)
&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200b;

Comment: Searching on $\text{Google}$ gives me the following link, where the solution is presented. - http://www.mathdb.org/resource_sharing/excalibur/v2_n4.pdf

Comment: Too lazy to write it up now, so please see http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/ProofOfPtolemysInequality.html and http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Ptolemy's_Inequality

Comment: Related:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886282/proof-of-ptolemys-theorem/3995818#3995818