# Proof of Ptolemy's Theorem

Tags: geometry, circles, plane-geometry

[image]

I am trying to prove using similar triangles without considering an arbitrary point on the diagonals which is the most common proof what we see in text books.

Let $HI=a$, $IJ=b$, $JC=c$ ,$CH=d$, $HL=x$, $LJ=e-x$, $CL=f-y$ and $LI=y$

we have $$\Delta HLC \sim \Delta ILJ $$ so we have

$$\frac{d}{b}=\frac{f-y}{e-x}=\frac{x}{y} \tag{1}$$ Also

$$\Delta CLJ \sim \Delta HLI$$ so

$$\frac{a}{c}=\frac{e-x}{y}=\frac{f-y}{x} \tag{2}$$  from $(1)$ and $(2)$ is it possible to prove that $$ac+bd=ef$$

Answer (score 1):

> from $(1)$ and $(2)$ is it possible to prove that $ac + bd = ef$

Not directly, as far as I can see. For one thing, Ptolemy's theorem "decays" nicely to $a c = a c$ in the degenerate case where $I \equiv J, b = 0, e = a, f = c$, while similarity-based proofs would not directly translate to the trivial case.

That said, the similarity of both pairs of triangles is equivalent to calculating the [Power of the Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) $L$ with respect to the given circle $LH\;LJ = LI\; LC$. The power of the point *is* related to the [Inversion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inversion.html) transformation, and it is indeed possible to prove [Ptolemy by Inversion](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/PtolemyByInversion.shtml). As said, however, that's not exactly an *immediate* consequence of the given similarity.

Answer (score 0):

As a practice to me learning geometry, I write an answer to this question :^) Note: $[ab]$ denotes the distance between point $a$ and point $b$

#### Introduction to geometric inversion:

For an origin centered circle C of radius R, geometric inversion map is defined in the following way:

$$ \tilde{z} = I_C (z) = \frac{R^2}{\overline{z}}$$

From this we get that a relation between conjugate and inverted point,

$$ \tilde{z} \cdot \overline{z} = R^2$$

Note that:

$$ | \tilde{z} | | \overline{z} | = | \tilde{z}| |z| = R^2$$
Also note that the transformation is involutive (self inverse)

Now let's see this transformation's effect on geometrical objects such as triangles:

[image]

Under inversion $ a \to \tilde{a}$ and $ b \to \tilde{b}$, note that:

$$ [qa][q \tilde{a} ] = R^2$$

Also,

$$ [qb][ q \tilde{b} ] =R^2$$

Hence,

$$ \frac{ [qa]}{[qb] } = \frac{ [q \tilde{b} ] }{ [ q \tilde{a} ]}$$

Hence with the common angle q, this implies

$$ \triangle qab \sim \triangle q\tilde{b} \tilde{a}$$

Hence,

$$ \frac{ [ab]}{ [\tilde{a} \tilde{b}] } =  \frac{[qa]}{[q \tilde{b}]}$$

Now,

$$ [ q \tilde{b} ] = \frac{R^2}{ [qb] }$$

This and rearrangement gives:

$$ [ \tilde{a} \tilde{b} ] = \frac{R^2}{ [ qa] [qb]}[ab] \tag{1}$$

### How are circles passing through center of inverting circle mapped under inversion?

[image]

Consider a Line outside the circle, take two points $a$ and $b$ and consider the inverses $ \tilde{a}$ and $ \tilde{b}$, from the previous triangle arguements we find $ \angle q \tilde{b} \tilde{a} = \frac{\pi}{2}$, now notice that as we vary $b$ this angle condition remains same. From inscribed angle theorem, we can say that locus of $ \tilde{b}$ is a circle.(2)

### Proof

[image]

Under inversion of a circle K centered at $a$, the circle containing the cyclic quadrilateral gets mapped abcd gets mapped to a line L (2)with the $ b \to \tilde{b}$ , $ c \to \tilde{c}$ , $ d \to \tilde{d}$

It is obvious that:

$$[ \tilde{b} \tilde{c} ] + [\tilde{c} \tilde{d}] = [\tilde{b} \tilde{d}]$$

Now,

$$ \frac{[bc]}{[ab][ac]} + \frac{[cd]}{[ac][ad]} = \frac{[bd]}{[ab][ad]}$$ (1)

$$ [bc][ad] + [cd][ab] = [bd][ac]$$

QED

All pictures from [Tristan Needham's Visual Complex Analsysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198534469)