# If $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ are consecutive vertices of a quadrilateral that lie on a circle prove the following

Tags: complex-analysis

If $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ are consecutive vertices of a quadrilateral that lie on a circle prove the following: $|z_1-z_3||z_2-z_4|=|z_1-z_2||z_3-z_4|+|z_1-z_4||z_2-z_3|$. I know that you can prove this without using the cross-ratio, but I would like to complete this proof using it. Here are some things I know:

1. The cross-ratio is real if and only if $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ lie on the same circle.
2. The cross-ratio is invariant under linear transformations, i.e. $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=(Tz_1,Tz_2,Tz_3,Tz_4)$.

I am not sure if (2) will be of any use, but I definitely think (1) would be helpful. Using (1) I can only get as far as: $|z_1-z_3||z_2-z_4|=C|z_1-z_4||z_2-z_3|$, where $C \geq 0$.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: After playing with the equation for a while this is what I concluded: Of course by simple verification, one indeed finds that $(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)=(z_1-z_2)(z_3-z_4)+(z_1-z_4)(z_2-z_3)$. Then we have $$\frac{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)}{(z_1-z_4)(z_2-z_3)}=\frac{(z_1-z_2)(z_3-z_4)}{(z_1-z_4)(z_2-z_3)}+1.$$ Now our result is proven if we can show that both of these quotients are real and positive. Well, the real part follows from the fact that a cross-ratio is real if and only if all four points lie on the same circle. Now for the positive part: The quotient on the left is the cross ratio $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)$ where $z_2 \rightarrow 1$, $z_3 \rightarrow 0$, $z_4 \rightarrow \infty$. Now this transformation, which is bijective, takes the circle that passes through these points to the real line. Therefore the arc from $z_4$ to $z_2$ is taken to $[-\infty,1]$, hence $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4) > 1$. A similar argument works to show that the other cross-ratio is also positive.

Is this reasoning correct? I guess we use the fact that continuous functions take connected sets to connected sets, so the image of these arcs must be connected.

Comment: [This is ptolemy's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3995818/688539) I've written a proof in linked using inversion (fully self contained)

Comment: Btw what is cross ratio?

Comment: @Buraian: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio#Definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. You have demonstrated that
$$
\frac{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)}{(z_1-z_4)(z_2-z_3)}=\frac{(z_1-z_2)(z_3-z_4)}{(z_1-z_4)(z_2-z_3)}+1
$$
and the quotient on the left is $> 1$. That implies that the quotient on the right is $> 0$. Therefore  all expressions are positive, and it follows that
$$
\left|\frac{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)}{(z_1-z_4)(z_2-z_3)}\right|=\left|\frac{(z_1-z_2)(z_3-z_4)}{(z_1-z_4)(z_2-z_3)}\right|+1 \, .
$$

Instead of a connectedness argument you can also use that Möbius transformation preserve orientation: The quotient on the left is equal to $T(z_1)$ where $T$ is the Möbius transformation which maps $z_2, z_3, z_4$ to $1, 0, \infty$, respectively. $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ are consecutive points on a circle. It follows that $T(z_1), 1, 0, \infty$ are consecutive points on the extended real axis (a generalized circle) and that is only possible if $T(z) > 1$.

Comment: If all expressions are positive, then how did the modulus thing equation follow?

Comment: @Buraian: If $a, b$ are positive with $a = b+1$ then $|a| = |b| +1$.

Comment: What if there is imaginary part in 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: @Buraian: There isn't. As OP already argued, the cross ratio is a real number because the four points lie on a circle. That is a fundamental property of the cross ratio.